# Eliminating the OS to maximise high-performance code?

Tags: kernel, bootloader

Suppose I want to run some computational experiments, probably some mathematical simulations, and I want to get the best performance out of the system. I don't want the OS using up a significant chunk of physical memory, and the endless list of system services competing for CPU access.

What is the best way to boot the computer into some sort of ultra-minimal environment, where I can run a compiled program that I wrote with C. I need access to physical memory and probably some rudimentary access to a hard drive (I'm okay with no file system, and just reading/writing things by their absolute addresses).

I tried writing my own bootloader and had mixed success. I think I was able to get into 64-bit mode (long mode), but I wasn't sure where to go from there, in terms of running more code and interacting with the full set of physical memory and the hdd.

It's probably a bit much to ask, but GP-GPU would probably be handy too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a fun project, but tbh I think that you'll be much better off with one of the many existing super-minimal Linux distros (google around for JEOS, Linxu from scratch and more) or - if your code is small enough - why not freedos with a 32 bits extender like HX.

At least by starting from al albeit very much stripped-down general computing platform you don't have to worry about trivial stuff like different underlying hardware, networking, basic display and command line interfaces.  All the time you win by *not* having to program that stuff can be invested in refining the mathematical model itself.

Comment: How about BareMetal OS?

Comment: @user1002358 I didn't know that one, looks interesting.  However, in its present state it looks *very* bare to me with only limited disk support and very basic network support (just 2 chipsets supported).  Whether it's useful for you depends on how well you can fit your requirements within these limitations - by experience (from using PC style hardware for embedded-style applications) I can only say, don't underestimate the importance of preexisting tools and support for a variety of hardware.